# How do I create a symmetric matrix with a linearly decreasing diagonal in MatLab?

Tags: matlab, diagonal

I'm trying to create a symmetric n by n matrix where the symmetry line is linearly decreasing from n to 1.

For example a 5 by 5 would be:

```
5 4 3 2 1 
4 4 3 2 1
3 3 3 2 1
2 2 2 2 1
1 1 1 1 1
```

Thanks

Comment: Please, share the code you wrote to try to solve the problem. Then you will find somebody willing to help you. The way you pose the question is like asking to somebody to do your work.

Comment: In case this is homework, here are some hints: Try [`min`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html) with [singleton expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/). Or [`gallery`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gallery.html) combined with [`rot90`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rot90.html)

Answer (score 2):

Using [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/), the `min` function will generate a square matrix from the combination of a row and a column vector, so the result can be gained by doing:

```
N = 5;
A = min( (N:-1:1).', (N:-1:1) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use:

```matlab
numRows = 5;

mI = repmat((1:numRows)', 1, numRows);
mJ = repmat((1:numRows), numRows, 1);

mA = flip(flip(min(mI, mJ), 1), 2)
```

With the answer given by:

```matlab
mA =

     5     4     3     2     1
     4     4     3     2     1
     3     3     3     2     1
     2     2     2     2     1
     1     1     1     1     1
```

Comment: You might want to give some explanation to this code, as `repmat()` isn't very intuitive to most (new) MATLAB users.